# How can I access VB String functions directly in the immediate window in Visual Studio Express 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have been using Visual Studio since VB6, as well as VBA behind various office applications (some complex Excel sheets, Access DBs etc).

I've always used the immediate window to quickly execute/evaluate expressions; for example, if I wanted to verify I was using a correct ascii code somewhere I could just jump to the immediate window and type `?Chr(34)` (which is a double-quote) for confirmation.

However, moving to VS 2010 Express it appears these functions have been removed from the scope of the immediate window:

```
> ?Chr(34)
'Chr' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

which is a right pain.  Further investigation shows that using:

```
> ?Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.Chr(34)
"
```

works perfectly... but do we *really* have to prefix simple, 3-character-long string helper functions with an entire namespace and module every time we want to use them?

### My question

Is it possible to "import" a namespace (eg: `Microsoft.VisualBasic`) into the scope of the immediate window and if so, how?

Comment: My guess: is Microsoft.VisualBasic imported when you're debugging? If so, it should work; otherwise, just try Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic before executing the immediate command.

Comment: Open VS, create a new Windows Forms Application project, click Debug -> Windows -> Immediate to get immediate Window, `?Chr(34)` throws error.  Add a button to the form that changes its text to `Chr(34)`, run project, click button, works fine.

Comment: Honestly, I would just try the community version of Visual Studio 2013 which is essentially the pro version included with MSDN. It can open your 2010 projects without problem unless you have a setup project type. In that case, there is a plugin you can use. [Differences](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onecode/archive/2014/11/12/differences-between-visual-studio-community-edition-and-express-editions.aspx)

Comment: The VB.NET compiler has hard-baked knowledge of namespaces, the IDE does not.  Technically you could put `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings` at the top of the source file and get what you want.